# How to create dynamic server controls in C# and how to append more records from the database to repeater control without loading all once again

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a repeater control on a page that I populate with 10 records from the database. There is a more button on the page; both are inside an update panel. The more button brings the next 10 records from the database. All I want to do is to append the new 10 records to the existing 10 records in the repeater. How would I do this?

I need it to work like Twitter and Facebook and load server side controls while appending new records to repeater control without paging.

This is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:repeater id="repStd" runat="server" onitemcommand="repStd_ItemCommand" 
    onitemdatabound="rptCore_ItemDataBound">                           
    <HeaderTemplate>                                                             
        <asp:Label ID="lnkStdName" runat="server" CommandName="Name" 
           CssClass="hrefclass">Name</asp:Label>                                        
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="headParent" id="STHeader" runat="server">                                                                          
            <asp:Label ID="lblStdName" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Project_Name") %>'></asp:Label>                                                                     
        </div>
        <div class="contentParent" id="STcontent" runat="server">                                                                  
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelST" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">                                                  
                <ContentTemplate>                                                                   
                    <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="STAsyncFileUpload_Pdf" runat="server" Width="500px" 
                    CompleteBackColor="White" OnClientUploadError="STuploadError" OnClientUploadComplete="STuploadComplete"                                                                                                                            
                    OnClientUploadStarted="STUploadedStartedPdfFile" UploadingBackColor="#CCDDEE"                                                                                                                            
                    UploaderStyle="Modern" ThrobberID="STinProgress" 
                    OnUploadedComplete="STPdf_FileUploadComplete" />                                                                           
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:repeater>
```

My itemdatabound:

```
public void rptCore_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //load controls data and calculations here.. like fileupload control etc
}
```

Comment: Not really clear from your description but it sounds like you need to use some Ajax code to call a get_10_more function.

Comment: @MRS check my answer, it will solve your problem..

Comment: @Shirish I need to load server side controls while appending new records to repeater control

Comment: @MRS on repeator you can not do that with out loading all data but you can load by my provided answer with ajax calling

Comment: @Shirish with your answer i can only create html controls but i need to use server side controls

Comment: @MRS Yes you can create that also by making dynamic unique ID of controls.. and call ajax with that id whatever you want to do on that control

Comment: @Shirish i am unable to add ajax AsyncFileUpload  control using Ajax calling as you suggested

Comment: @Shirish i think you are unable understand my problem as i am unable to add server side  AsyncFileUpload control using Ajax calling as you suggested so please suggest me regarding this

Comment: @MRS it is also possible just use dynamic id of control..

Comment: @Shirish still not clear please can you provide me a sample code or link to  review

Comment: @Shirish thanks to provide a helpful solution can you please share same links to add ajax AsyncFileUpload control(only) using ajax calling .because i am using this control  throughout my application

Comment: @MRS it is same process you have to maintain dynamic ID only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement use `for/Foreach` loop by calling `table/div` structure in place of repeater..

For your logic call 10 records from last index and add in your `table/div`.

This will solve your problem and it is very effective without making any performance issue..

For eg. follow below logic -

```
DataTable dt = GetYourRows(); 
String html = "";
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
 html += "<div>"+dr["column"].ToString();+"</div>";
}
```

then use your `html` anywhere in your existing HTML code

Comment: @MRS for reference try this - https://humrahimcs.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/dynamically-create-multiple-file-upload-control-with-asp-net-c/

Comment: @MRS for reference try this - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Uploading-Multiple-Files-using-JavaScript-Dynamic-FileUpload-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: @MRS for reference try this -http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24914/Multiple-Dynamic-File-Uploading